# "__LAST__" (in tmpl_if) not always works in Perl HTML::Template

Tags: perl, perl-html-template

I have the following line in my tmpl file:

```
<td><TMPL_LOOP SIGNS><TMPL_VAR LEFT_SIGN> - <TMPL_VAR RIGHT_SIGN><TMPL_UNLESS __LAST__></br></TMPL_UNLESS></TMPL_LOOP></td>
```

When refreshing the page it switches between both displays (sometimes refresh leads to the same display and not necessarily switch it):

Display1 (new line between each line - as expected):

```
AA1 - AA2
BB1 - BB2
CC1 - CC2
```

Display2 (no new line between the last item):

```
AA1 - AA2
BB1 - BB2CC1 - CC2
```

Recently I upgraded Perl to version 5.24.3 and I suspect that `__LAST__` stop working as expected (no always recognize the last item in the loop).
I am using the module "HTML::Template".

I changed the html to (`__FIRST__` instead of `__LAST__`):

```
<td><TMPL_LOOP SIGNS><TMPL_UNLESS __FIRST__></br></TMPL_UNLESS><TMPL_VAR LEFT_SIGN> - <TMPL_VAR RIGHT_SIGN></TMPL_LOOP></td>
```

and it works always as expected.

I couldn't find any reference to this issue.

Is it really a bug with `__LAST__`?

Comment: What library do you use that provides the `__LAST__`? It's not part of Perl itself.

Comment: do you mean to "HTML::Template"?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant, minimal Perl code to reproduce the output. [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML::Template then check the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template#Miscellaneous-Options). You might need to set `loop_context_vars` option and use lowercase `__last__` or `__first__`.
I guess that code with `__FIRST__` works because it always outputs `<br>`

Comment: Thanks. but changing to lower case didn't solve the problem. It is an old code and the only change was the Perl and mod_perl upgrade.

Comment: `loop_context_vars` is set to `false` by default

Comment: How it is possible that I am getting a different behavior each time I am refreshing the page or it works fine with __FIRST__? How can I set it to true?